# How can I add 2 arguments to 1 function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in Rails, I'm doing tutorial by Hartl but I want to add sometimes something special from me to the code. I'm doing microposts right now and I want to add "delete" function to delete micropost, but I want this function to be visible only for admin and for user who made this micropost. Now I don't know how to do that, because when I want to setup `<% if current_user(micropost.user) && user.admin %>` I get an error `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`.
In `session_helper.rb` I have function `def current_user` not `def current_user(micropost.user)` I know that but can I add somehow this micropost.user and get this done? Bellow all code:

`app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb`

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, size: 50), micropost.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %></span>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user(micropost.user) && user.admin %>
   <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete,
                         data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

`app/helpers/session_helper.html.erb`

```
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply be checking `if current_user == micropost.user`. There is no reason to add an argument to `current_user`, and doing so would make the purpose of that method much less obvious. The  method `current_user(something)` in no way implies an equality check between the current user and the argument, and violates a pretty common Rails practice of defining a method called `current_user` to return the currently authenticated user.

If you want to define an *additional* method that checks whether the given user is the current user, you should use `current_user?(user)`. It would be used like this...

```
<% if current_user?(micropost.user) && user.admin %>
```

and defined like this:

```
def current_user?(user)
  current_user == user
end
```

Comment: Damn so easy I didn't think about it. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, do you have any suggestions how can I define function for admin as well? When I click delete button as admin I get redirected to root_url without deleting the post...

Answer (score 0):

meagar is correct, you should not add parameters to that method. But to allow for parameters all you would have to do is change the def line to something like that, then just reference the `user` argument where you want to call it, again bad idea but your are an adult.

```
def current_user(user)
```